Magnetic moment of a paramagnetic cylinder
I am currently struggling with a problem where I have to calculate the magnetic moment $M$ of a
cylinder of radius $R$ and height $h$ made up of a paramagnetic material (aluminium) and under a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ (supposedly uniform).
I searched a little bit on the internet and didn't find any convincing formulas or theorems (e.g.: Ampere's theorem for magnetostatics) to solve for the magnetic moments of materials.
It would be very nice if you could just give me the methodology or formulas to solve such problems.

The magnetization field $\vec{M}$ obeys
$$
\vec{B} = \mu_0 \left(\vec{H}+\vec{M}\right),
$$
where $B$ and $H$ are the magnetic fields. In many materials we usually have
$$
\vec{B} = \mu \vec{H} \implies \vec{M} = \dfrac{\mu-\mu_0}{\mu_0} \vec{H} = \dfrac{\mu-\mu_0}{\mu\mu_0} \vec{B}.
$$
We say that these have a linear relation.
Now, the magnetic moment $\vec{m}$ of an object is usually defined as
$$
\vec{m} = \int_{\text{Object}}  dV\vec{M},
$$
which is just the total magnetization in the material, which for a linear material becomes
$$
\vec{m} = \dfrac{\mu-\mu_0}{\mu\mu_0} \int_{\text{Object}}  dV \vec{B}.
$$
I would leave to you to fill in the specifics of your problem ;)

Thank you Gabriel :)
